# Label shapes for model output shape (batch_size,1,1,n_classes) and SparseCategoricalCrossEntropy Loss

Tags: tensorflow, keras, image-classification, sparsecategoricalcrossentropy

I'm using tensorflow/keras to build an image classification model.  The labels are provided as integers, & so I'm using `tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossEntropy` as documented at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy

The model has output shape `(batch_size,1,1,n_classes)`.

What shape do the labels need to have?

It seems like the labels should have the shape `(batch_size,1,1,n_classes)`.
However, from a few tests, it seems like `(batch_size,)` works too.

Often models have output shape `(batch_size,n_classes)` and when using `SparseCategoricalCrossEntropy` the label shape is (batch_size,).

Comment: Actually the model output shape should be `(n_batches,n_classes)` and labels shape `(n_batches,)`.  If your model output is `(batch_size,1,1,n_classes)` which does not make sense why you have 2 one dimensions , then the labels should be `(n_batches,1,1,1)`.

Comment: The model output shape during training is `(batch_size,1,1,n_classes)` b/c I want the model to be able to handle variable size inputs.  The model output shape in general is `(batch_size,None,None,n_classes)` b/c the model input shape is `(batch_size,None,None,3)`